# TYPO3: How do I set the correct id in locallang for a flux:field inside a flux:object?

Tags: typo3, translation, fluid

I'm creating a Flexible Content Element.

In my template configuration flux form I have a field, in an object, in a section. In my locallang.xlf, I can label my object and section, but I haven't been able to label my field successfully.

My template configuration looks like:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="element">
        <flux:form.section name="settings.mysection">
            <flux:form.object name="myobject">
                <flux:field.input name="myfield" />
            </flux:form.object>
        </flux:form.section>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

The relevant part of my locallang.xlf looks like:

```
<trans-unit id="flux.element.sections.settings.mysection">
    <source>This works</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="flux.element.objects.myobject">
    <source>This also works</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="flux.element.fields.myfield">
    <source>This doesn't work</source>
</trans-unit>
```

What should the id attribute be to label 'myfield'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AdditionalConfiguration.php`, add the following:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['lang']['debug'] = true;
```

Now you will see the full language label paths in the backend:

```
flux.element.objects.myobject.myfield
```

---

It seems this was changed for TYPO3 8.7 https://forge.typo3.org/issues/71095 to

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['languageDebug'] = true;
```